# "Key column 'username' doesn't exist in table"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am creating three tables and when trying to tie the primary and foreign keys I am receiving the error message "Key column 'username' doesn't exist in table".

Could someone take a look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong?  I have tried dropping the database and revamped the tables a few times but I am still getting the same message.  Here is my code, thank you in advance for any help!

```
 create database testproject
 use testproject
 create table caller_info
 (
   caller_id int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key not null,
   first_name varchar(35) not null, 
   Last_name varchar(35) not null, 
   phone_number int(25) not null
 );  
create table caller_call_record
(
    call_record_id int(11),
    Call_Description varchar(50), 
    franchise_id int(10) not null, 
    email varchar(40) not null, 
    username varchar(25) primary key not null
);
create table caller_escalation
(
    call_escalation_id int(11) unsigned auto_increment not null, 
    Second_Level varchar(5) not null, 
    caller_id int(11) not null, 
    PRIMARY KEY(call_escalation_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(caller_id) 
    REFERENCES caller_info(caller_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES caller_call_record(username)
);
```

Comment: Your table `caller_escalation` does not have the column `username`.  Either add that column, or change the FK reference.

Comment: Your caller_call_record has no user name in it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am starting a project and the my thought is building a database where if a caller were to call into the support center this program would be used to record the users information.  Very generic but I am running into errors.  I just updated my last table to - create table caller_escalation(call_escalation_id int(11) unsigned auto_increment not null, Second_Level varchar(5) not null, caller_id int(11) not null, username varchar(25) not null, PRIMARY KEY(call_escalation_id), FOREIGN KEY(caller_id) REFERENCES caller_info(caller_id), FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES caller_call_record(username));

Comment: and I am now getting the error can not add foreign key constraints

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
create table caller_call_record
(
            call_record_id int(11),
            Call_Description varchar(50), 
            franchise_id int(10) not null, 
            email varchar(40) not null, 
            username varchar(25) not null,
            PRIMARY KEY (username)    
    );



create table caller_escalation
(
    call_escalation_id int(11) unsigned auto_increment not null, 
    Second_Level varchar(5) not null, 
    caller_id int(11) not null,
    username varchar(25) not null, 
    PRIMARY KEY(call_escalation_id,username),
    FOREIGN KEY(caller_id) 
    REFERENCES caller_info(caller_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES caller_call_record
);
```

Comment: DRWPIL this is giving me the same doesn't exist error message.

Answer (score 0):

The table caller_escalation also needs a column username, which is not there

```
create table caller_escalation
(
    call_escalation_id int(11) unsigned auto_increment not null, 
    Second_Level varchar(5) not null, 
    caller_id int(11) unsigned not null, ;; <--- added unsigned type here
    PRIMARY KEY(call_escalation_id),
    username varchar(25) not null,       ;; <--- added field here
    FOREIGN KEY(caller_id) 
    REFERENCES caller_info(caller_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES caller_call_record (username)
);
```

Also ensure the column data types are the same in both tables.  You have "caller_id int(11) unsigned" in caller_info and "caller_id int(11)" in caller_escalation. I added the unsigned specifier above to make it work.

Comment: It is giving me the error, can not add foreign key constraints.  Now we see my pain, I am getting stumped.

Comment: make sure the foreign key columns are the same type as the primary  key in the linked columns. You have "caller_id int(11) unsigned" in caller_info and "caller_id int(11)" in caller_escalation.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, your table `caller_escalation` needs a column called `username` in order to create the foreign key.

It sounds like once you've added that, you're now getting a `Cannot add foreign key constraint` error from MySQL. The first thing that comes to mind with this kind of error is that you're using the wrong engine for your tables. You are most likely using `MyISAM` which does not support foreign key references - in order to use these, you will need to change the engine on all of your tables to `InnoDB`.